# Hyperbolic distance

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, knot-theory

Find the hyperbolic distance between $(0; 0; 0)$ and $(0; 0; \frac12)$ in the Poincare model.
Recall that the Poincare model deems $d(P_1; P_2)=\int\frac{2}{1-r^2}ds$.
What about the distance between $(0; 0; 0)$ and $(0; 0; A)$ as $A$ approaches $1$?

As we integrate along a horizontal line, the path differential $ds$ consists only of a
horizontal component, i.e. $dy = dz = 0$ but still stuck.

Comment: Can you write down the integral you get from parametrisation of the path?

Comment: I ended up getting the integral{2/(1-x^2)dx from x=0 to 1/2 which is a partial fraction that equals integral{1/(X+1)- 1/(x-1)} from X= 0 to 1/2. Integrating this I got ln(x+1)-ln(X-1) from 0 to 1/2, which gave me ln(3)-ln(2)-Pi*i+ln(2)+Pi*i= ln(3). I think thats the answer to the first part.

Comment: Close. $$\frac{2}{1-x^2} = \frac{1}{1+x} + \frac{1}{1-x},$$ and the primitive is $\log (1+x) - \log (1-x)$, so there ought to be no $\pi i$ terms. They cancel out, however, so your end result is correct. Getting the answer to the second part should not be difficult having the first.